# Traversing structs using pointer++

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

This might be a dumb question but I'm just learning C.

I have declared:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct STRUCTURE{
    char name[30];
}STRUCT;

int main(void){
    STRUCT struct1[30] // declaring 30 structs.
    STRUCT *pointer;
    pointer = &struct1;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I wanted to reference to specific struct (of the 30 structs) I could do it like:

```
&struct[0] // first struct's memory location
&struct[1] // second struct's memory location 
...
&struct[i] // where i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 29
```

But how would I do it using the pointer?

I thought by incrementing the pointer I could traverse the structs:

```
pointer++
```

But I can't seem to be getting from `struct1[i]` to `struct1[i+1]` with `pointer++`

Comment: `pointer = &struct1;` is invalid C. Didn't you get a message from the compiler? Which compiler are you using and what warning levels are used? Also, no semicolon here: `STRUCT struct1[30]`

Comment: "But I can't seem to be getting from struct1[i] to struct1[i+1] with pointer++" Well, that's how it works.... But tells how you reached that conclusion. You must have some code!!! Post it

Comment: name of an array is already a pointer to its first element no need for & and taking its address with `&struct1` would give you a pointer to a pointer, which is not what you want.

Comment: OT: naming your personal datatype "STRUCT" is legal, but still not a good idea. Use your imagination!!

Comment: @mantissa Strictly `&struct1` is not a pointer to pointer. It's a pointer to array.

Comment: "... but I'm just learning C." Okay, here is the very first and very important thing to learn about C: Make sure to set your compiler to a high warning level and fix all warnings before running the program. For `gcc` I will at least recommend: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters this assignment

```
pointer = &struct1;
```

is incorrect. The expression in the right side of the assignment `&struct1` has the pointer type `STRUCT ( * )[30]` while the operand in the left side has the pointer type `STRUCT *` and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another.

Instead you need to write

```
STRUCT struct1[30] // declaring 30 structs.
STRUCT *pointer;
pointer = struct1;
```

In this case the array designator `struct1` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element and the pointer `pointer` will point to that first element of the array `struct1` and using the pointer arithmetic you can access any element of the array.

For example, to output strings stored in the data member `name` of elements of the array (provided that they are initialized) using for loop you can write

```
for ( STRUCT *p = struct1; p != struct1 + 30; ++p )
{
    printf( "%s ", p->name );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

Or instead of using the magic number 30 you could introduce a named constant as for example

```
enum { N = 30 };
STRUCT struct1[N];
```

and the n to write the loop like

```
for ( STRUCT *p = struct1; p != struct1 + N; ++p )
{
    printf( "%s ", p->name );
}
putchar( '\n' );
```

In this case if you will want to change the size of the array it will be enough to change the program only in one place in the enumeration declaration.

Pay attention to that the expression

`pointer[i]` is equivalent to the expression `*( pointer + i] )`. And the expression `&pointer[i]` is correspondingly equivalent to `pointer + i`.